# Relationship between matrix's eigenvalue and rank

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Can we determine the rank of a matrix from its eigenvalues ? Let's say there is a matrix with eigenvalues (0,0,1,2,3), can we determine its rank ?

Comment: In order to make progress on problems like this, first write down what rank means. (This should be part of your question here, as well.) How do the eigenvalues affect the rank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rank of an $m\times n$ matrix is $n-\dim\ker A$, therefore for square matrices the rank is completely determined by the *geometric multiplicity* of the eigenvalue $0$. Tautologically, the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ in the matrix $A$ is just $m_g(\lambda)=\dim\ker (A-\lambda I)$. $\lambda$ is then an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $m_g(\lambda)\ge1$.

There is the issue of whether you are listing the eigenvalues by geometric multiplicity or by *algebraic multiplicity*. The algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is $$m_a(\lambda)=\max\{k\in\Bbb N\,:\, (x-\lambda)^k\mid \det(A-xI)\},$$ id est, the exponent with which $(x-\lambda)$ appears in the factorization of the characteristic polynomial of $A$.
It is true that $$m_a(\lambda)\ge1\Leftrightarrow m_g(\lambda)\ge1\Leftrightarrow \lambda\text{ is an eigenvalue of }A,$$
but in general $m_g(\lambda)\le m_a(\lambda)$, and therefore $n-m_a(0)\le \operatorname{rk}A$. By the previous remark that $m_g(0)\ge 1\Leftrightarrow m_a(0)\ge1$, this becomes $n-m_a(0)\le \operatorname{rk}A\le n-1$ as soon as $m_a(0)\ne0$.

For an instance of that inequality being effective, if in your example you are indicating the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalues, then that piece of information alone does not distinguish the cases $$\operatorname{rk}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&2&0\\ 0&0&0&0&3\end{bmatrix}=4\\ \operatorname{rk}\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&2&0\\ 0&0&0&0&3\end{bmatrix}=3$$

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The rank is the number of eigenvalues that are unequal to zero.

But beware, this is only true for diagonalizable matrices. For arbitrary matrices, look at Saucy O'Paths answer.

Comment: This is not true. For example $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& 0& 1\end{bmatrix}$ has 1 eigenvalue unequal to zero but its rank is 2.

Comment: @obareey That matrix has the eigen value 1 twice. But yeah I could have been more precise for eigen values that occur more than once.

Comment: No it has eigenvalue 0 twice and eigenvalue 1 once.

Comment: Argh, I forgot about the Jordan form!

Comment: For diagonalizable matrices, the fact stated should be true, right?

Comment: If a matrix is diagonalizable algebraic multiplicity of its eigenvalues are equal to their geometric multiplicity. This is why it is true for diagonalizable matrices. But in its core it is about the geometric multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue as stated in Saucy O'Path's answer.

Comment: Alright. I edited my answer accordingly!

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot